# performing same action for all users connected in same room in socket.io using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to make a website similar to https://www.omegle.com/ where it is a one-to-one conversation at a time.

Where if any of connected user clicks on disconnect button to end the chat,  it has to show a `new chat` `div` to both users.

But the problem is that the `new chat` `div` is only showing to the user which click on the disconnect button.

This is my client-side code

```
 $disconnect.click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('user disconnect', socket.id, (data) => {
        if(data){
            $messageForm.hide();
            $newChat.show();
        }
    });
});
```

I am not getting any idea to solve this problem. Please, someone, help me in this.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Did you created room for both clients on Server?

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn yes i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is you using an `emit` callback. But this callback only response to source client.

So at here you can change your Client side handler to:

`socket.partner_id` is your partner on conversation.

```
$disconnect.click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('user disconnect', socket.partner_id, (data) => {
        if(data){
            console.log('Closed chat room by your self')
            $messageForm.hide();
            $newChat.show();
        }
    });
});
socket.on('user disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Closed chat room by your partner')
    $messageForm.hide();
    $newChat.show();
})
```

And your Server side to:

```
socket.on('user disconnect', function (partner_id, fn) {
    socket.broadcast.to(partner_id).emit('user disconnect');
    fn(true);
}))
```

Hope this help.

Comment: thnx. perfect logic.